# Unable to hide command prompt in C# windows form application visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process, cmd

I have made an application in C# visual studio 2010. In this application I am sending `ping` command to `cmd` and the receiving the output of the `cmd` in a `RichTextBox`. Here is my code:-

```
void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
        MethodInvoker append = () => txtOutput.Text += newLine;
        txtOutput.BeginInvoke(append);
    }
}
private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string command = "/c ping " + txtPing.Text;

    ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD", command);

    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();

    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
    proc.Start();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

my code is working great but the issue is `cmd` is also getting popup when I click on `start` button. And I want to hide this `cmd` as I want to show output only in `RichTextBox.` So, my question is, how can I hide `cmd` in my application.
here is the screen shot of my problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

This worked for me.

Comment: thanks but It's not working

Comment: Try this : procStartInfo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; Along with syntax I mentioned

Comment: @Partha Please make your mind up. Answer says one thing, comments another.

Comment: Got my answer, it's  proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, my answer worked for me. The comments is what I got by googling.

Comment: @Tabish That's exactly what the answer says!

Comment: may be there are more than one way to do this,any way thanks for your help bro,

Comment: First of all you say that this "doesn't work", whatever that means. Then you say that it does work.

Comment: @Partha please provide all possible solutions in this single answer to let people not to read all the comments (they may would not even do that).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines. This worked for me.

```
 procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Comment: One cmd window is still there , showing ping results..

Comment: Do the same for that window too!

Comment: @Tabish That's because you aren't doing it right.

Comment: I got it, command is a bit diffrent,  it's  proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Any way thanks for your help bro, your method should be  also right